# as3 dispatching events

Tags: actionscript-3, events

when dispatching events in as3 I always have to extend class from sprite, or movieclip, but when I don't have display objects I don't wont to extend to sprite or movieclip. What is the most light class that I can extend, i mean no display object, and stile do use event dispatching?

Answer (score 1):

[flash.events.EventDispatcher](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html)

EventDispatcher is the base class for all classes in AS3 that dispatch events.  The easiest way for you to create a class that can dispatch events is to have your class extend EventDispatcher.

Sometimes however, that is not possible.  If, for example, your class already extends a different class that is not descended from EventDispatcher, then you are stuck, because classes and only extend one superclass.  The solution in this case is to make your class implement [IEventDispatcher](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/IEventDispatcher.html), and hand off the functionality of the required methods to an instance of EventDispatcher instead.